# How do I console.log the onclick of zoom-in and zoom-out to get the zoom level

Tags: leaflet, react

How do I get the zoom level console when I click on the leaflet-control-zoom leaflet-bar leaflet-control

```
<MapContainer center={[-16.4391, 233.2813]} zoom={3} scrollWheelZoom={false} style={{ height: '99.84vh', width: '100wh' }} >
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48264529/how-to-get-map-object-in-react-leaflet-on-zoom-change-event

Answer (score 0):

According to https://leafletjs.com/examples/zoom-levels/ you can define a JS function like:

```
map.on('zoomstart', function (ev) {
    console.log('Zoom start: ' + map.getZoom());
});
```

Or:

```
map.on('zoomend', function (ev) {
    console.log('Zoom end: ' + map.getZoom());
});
```

In each case, the result will be the zoom level, like this:

[image: Zoom level]

I suggest you review this example as well: https://leafletjs.com/examples/zoom-levels/example-delta.html